fluentui/web-components in vuejs no styling
I have followed this integration guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/integrations/vue
After following it and using some fluent components in a view, they just appear as raw HTML elements.
How to apply the correct fluent styling?

hey just appear as raw HTML elements. Please elaborate.
